# Cmake build error on Fedora 37 ; cannot find UDev library

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, sfml

I was trying to make some games in SFML, download the source code on github but i have some dependencies issues while trying to build the code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Zdy.png)

I'm working on Fedora 37.
Anyone know how to solve it ?

The library exit on /usr/lib/udev so i guess it's a path issues but i already try to export it on the $PATH but didn't work either.

Comment: It says you have not installed the header files.  The libraries have to be there for your system to work at all.

Comment: Why are you building SFML at all?  It's been in the Fedora repo forever.

Comment: When i try to build SFML with my c++ code, it cannot find it so that's why i try to installed it manually

Comment: And how do you install this header ? Can't find it

Comment: Fedora normally just installs the runtime libraries for packages.  If you want to do development with a library you install the `-devel` package which gives you headers and documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to build SFML on Fedora since it is in the repos.  Just do

```
dnf install SFML SFML-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to build SFML from sources in Fedora 37, you have to

```
# dnf install systemd-devel
```

package, it will add missing udev dependency.